# DataFrame: Cómo contar datos en función de grupos de dummies (condición)?

Tags: python, pandas

busco contar datos en una columna (var), acorde a "grupos" de una dummy (condición). Me da la impresión que es bastante sencillo pero no se me ha ocurrido como hacerlo. Mi data es así:

```
dummy  var  
 0      0    
 0      0    
 0      0    
 0      0
 1      0
 1      0
 1      1
 1      1
 1      0
 0      0
 0      0
 0      0
 1      1
 1      0
 1      1  
 0      0
...    ...
```

Necesito que quede así:

```
dummy  var  
 0      0    
 0      0    
 0      0    
 0      0
 1      0
 1      0
 1      1 # <-- Comienza a contar primer grupo de dummies
 1      2
 1      0
 0      0
 0      0
 0      0
 1      1 # <-- Al segundo grupo de dummies, se resetea la cuenta.
 1      0
 1      2  
 0      0
...    ...
```

Como pueden ver, en el primer grupo de dummies (1) empieza a contar y llega hasta 2. Luego en el segundo grupo de dummies se resetea la cuenta en "var". Se me ocurre que se podría hacer haciendo que cada grupo de "dummies" tuviera un valor distinto, y luego hacer una especie de cumsum bygroup, pero lo logro dilucidarlo. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo lograr esto? Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

EDIT:

```
        # Generar grupos en variable dummy
        sumar=0
        for x,y in enumerate(df['dummy']):
            if df['dummy'][x]==1:
                sumar = sumar + 1
                df['dummy'][x] = df['dummy'][x] + sumar
                
 
        # Cumsum en función de los grupos creados.
        df['var'] = df['var'].groupby(df['dummy']).cumsum()
```

Como ven, esto me suma todas las dummies, incluso dentro del mismo grupo.

Comment: Incluye el código de tu intento, por favor.

Comment: Como dice @marmurar incluye el código para que sepamos que hay. Si solo quieres contar las veces que aparece el número 1. Siempre puedes usar el método `sum()`

Comment: Listo, lo agregué en Edit. Como indiqué, no logro ejecutar mi idea pues tengo problemas al armar los grupos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, esto logró lo que buscaba. No es la solución más elegante, pero funciona.

```
        df['final'] = df['var']
        
        for x,y in enumerate(df['final']):
            if df['dummy'][x]==1:        
                df['final'][x] = df['final'][x]+df['final'][x-1] 

        df['final'] = np.where(df['final'].shift(1)==df['final'],0,df['final'])
```

Saludos